Show custom page when SocketException occurs
So I want to catch a SocketException anywhere in the app and show a nice warning to say there is no internet connection.
I have the following code inside main() which works but only when there is no screen pushed on top of the home screen, or any overlays or bottom sheet, otherwise those screens/overlays are still visible (I am not using scaffold here because was getting lots of render errors when using this):
  ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) {
    if (details.exception is SocketException) {
      return const Material(child: NoInternetWarningPage());
    }
    return Material(child: AllOtherErrorsPage());
  }

I have tried to keep removing pages from the navigation (I'm using GoRouter) before returning the NoInternetWarningPage like the following, but it created an infinite loop for some reason:
      if (navigatorKey.currentContext != null) {
        while (GoRouter.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).canPop()) {
          GoRouter.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!).pop();
        }
      }

